# How can I get the solution in edit section when I use the realm save method?

Tags: ios, xcode, realm

when I run the program then it will run successfully 
but when I'm going on editing section then it will crash.. but when I put the all realm code in edit section that time my app will again crash... .
what is the reason behind this all thing?? Anybody can help me out!!

```
    @IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {
       let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
       if textField.text?.characters.count > 0 {
           let newNotodoItem = NoToDoItem()
           newNotodoItem.name = textField.text!
           realm.transactionWithBlock() {
               realm.addObject(newNotodoItem)
           }
           self.tableView.reloadData() 
       }
       self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

       if let item = itemToEdit {
           item.text = textField.text!
           textField.becomeFirstResponder()
       } else {
           let item = NoToDoItem()
       }
   }
```

Comment: Can you try to explain what you're trying to achieve? It is not quite clear from the code you provide. What are the exceptions, you're seeing when your app crashes?

Comment: thanks for asking..but now I got the solution.and my question is whenever i was add an item to the data will successfully save , but the same procedure for editing i did then app will crash...

Answer (score 0):

```
This is my answer
      if let item = itemToEdit {
        let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
        realm.beginWriteTransaction()
        item.title = textField.text!
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        item.textDescription = textAreaDescription.text!
        textAreaDescription.becomeFirstResponder()
        item.dateTime = dateTime
        realm.addObject(item)
         _ = try? realm.commitWriteTransaction()

        delegate?.itemDetailViewController(self, didFinishEditingItem: item)
```

}